# MVC5 EF Entity apparently saving, but is null when retrieved

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an `Account` class that holds a list of `Payments`, which holds a list of `Products` that are `Pending`, `Sold` or `Refunded`.

When selecting the `Products` to pay for, I can add them into a `Payment` object and then save the whole object to an `Account`.

However, when I retrieve the account in the `Pay` action, `Account.Payments` is null.

Here is the `AddProduct` action:

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(List<Product> products)
{
    //var acc = Account.FetchAccountFromIdentity(User.Identity.GetUserName());
    var username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
    var acc = db.Accounts.First(u => u.EmailAddress == username);
    var payment = new Payment();

    foreach (var product in products)
    {
        if (product.IsSelected)
        {
            var tempProduct = db.Products.Find(product.ProductID);
            payment.Products.Add(tempProduct);
            payment.PaymentStatus = enPaymentStatus.Pending;
            payment.Gross += tempProduct.Price;
            payment.Vat += tempProduct.Price * 0.2;
            payment.Net += payment.Gross - payment.Vat;
         }
    }
    payment.AccountID = acc;
    if (acc.Payments == null) acc.Payments = new List<Payment>();
    acc.Payments.Add(payment);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Pay", "Products", new {id = acc.AccountID} );
}
```

`acc.Payments` is correctly populated with any relevant payments at this point.

And then the `Pay` action:

```
    public ActionResult Pay(int? id)
    {
        var acc = db.Accounts.Find(id);
        var data = new AccountPaymentView
        {
            Account =  acc,
            Payment = acc.Payments.First(p => p.PaymentStatus == enPaymentStatus.Pending)
        };

        return View(data);
    }
```

`acc.Payments` is now null!?

Any idea as to what I must be doing wrong?

*Edit*
Now with Account Class:

```
    public class Account
    {
        [Key]
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        public int AccountID { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "Title")]
        public string Salutation { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Display(Name = "Password")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "Passwords do not match. Please try again.")]
        [Display(Name = "Confirm Password")]
        public string ConfirmPass { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress)]
        [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
        public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<Payment> Payments { get; set; }
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
        public virtual  ICollection<DateTime> VistsList { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public enAccountType AccountType { get; set; }
}
```

*Edit 2*
Here is the OnModelCreating method on the DBContext (Removed unrelated parts). I've got to me missing something glaringly obvious?

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>()
        .Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasOptional(x => x.Addresses).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasOptional(x => x.Payments).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasOptional(x => x.Products).WithMany();
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasOptional(x => x.AccountID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasKey(x => x.PaymentID);

}
```

Edit 3
Checked out the Account.FetchAccountFromIdentity() and it does open a new context. So that has now been removed and I now use a context within the AddProduct method (code updated above).

Now I am getting the following error when saving!!!

```
An object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[PPPv2.Models.Payment, PPPv2,
Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]' 
cannot be set or removed from the Value property of an EntityReference of type 'PPPv2.Models.Payment'.
```

I've tried forcing the PK relationships in the OnModelCreating method, but it didn't seem to help.

For clarity, here is the Payment class:

```
public class Payment
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int PaymentID { get; set; }
    public virtual Account AccountID { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }
    public double Gross { get; set; }
    public double Net { get; set; }
    public double Vat { get; set; }
    public string TransactionCode { get; set; }
    public enPaymentStatus PaymentStatus { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime PaidOn { get; set; }

    public Payment()
    {
        Products = new List<Product>();
        Gross = 0.0;
        Net = 0.0;
        Vat = 0.0;
        IsDeleted = false;
        PaidOn = new DateTime(2000, 1, 1, 0, 0,0);
    }

}
```

Edit 4
As requested, here is the Product model:

```
public class Product 
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }
    public string Name   { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "£{0:#,###0.00}")]
    public double Price { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Currency)]
    [Display(Name = "Total Estimated Legal Cost")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "£{0:#,###0.00}")]
    public double EstimatedTotalLegalCost { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Overview> Overviews { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Process> Processes { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime LastUpdated { get; set; }
    public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: What is your Account model?

Comment: OK, the `Payments` are set up with the `virtual` keyword -> lazy loading is enabled. Try accessing the `.Payments` navigation property (`var first = acc.Payments.FirstOrDefault()`) and it should be automagically loaded from the database.

Comment: I put it into the Pay Action as: (var firstPayment = acc.Payments.FirstOrDefault();) but it's still being brought forward as null :(

Comment: I would honestly not use navigation properties to do saving and loading. This can create some really really obscure sql and possibly hammer the database. You need to utilise the database, stored procs and triggers.

Comment: After `db.SaveChanges();` in `AddProduct` are you able to see the data in the database? @No1_Melman That isn't true at all. Stored procs are unnecessary here.

Comment: Interesting, after db.SaveChanges(); the db is empty?! :/

Comment: @Shoe it is unknown to both of us whether they are or aren't necessary here, the way to find out would be to Profile the transaction to see how many calls are being made to the database.

Comment: Does `Account.FetchAccountFromIdentity` use the same context as you are saving against? Maybe post the code from there. Also please use `@name` to tag people so that they know you've responded.

Comment: @Shoe I'll start using the @ name going forward. Account.FetchAccountFromIdentity turned out to be using a seperate instance of the same db context. This has now been removed and now I have a different problem with the db.SaveChanges (added above).

Comment: Remove these lines `if (acc.Payments == null) acc.Payments = new List<Payment>(); acc.Payments.Add(payment);` and just do `payment.AccountId = acc.AccountId;`

Comment: @Shoe Sorry, tried that just now and neither the Payments table, nor the acc.Payments ends up with any Payment objects in them still :/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you look at the tables that the Entity Framework has generated, you'll see there's only three of them. Given your data model, there should be junction tables that map `Account` and `Payment` objects to one another (same goes for `Payment` and `Product`, and you'll likely need to do the same for the other collections you have).

The exception you are getting regarding being unable to cast a `List` of `Products` to a single one is because your data model indicated that `Products` was a collection, yet the database table was actually storing this as foreign-key (i.e., single entity) relationship between `Payment` and `Product`.

If I change the code in the `OnModelCreating` method to the following, your `AddProducts` method works as intended.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

    modelBuilder.Properties<DateTime>().Configure(c => c.HasColumnType("datetime2"));

    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(x => x.Addresses)
        .WithMany().Map(t => t.ToTable("AccountAddresses"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Account>().HasMany(x => x.Payments)
        .WithMany().Map(t => t.ToTable("AccountPayments"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasMany(x => x.Products)
        .WithMany().Map(t => t.ToTable("PaymentProducts"));
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasOptional(x => x.AccountID);
    modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasKey(x => x.PaymentID);
}
```

The change was going from code like:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasOptional(x => x.Products).WithMany();
```

To:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Payment>().HasMany(x => x.Products).WithMany().Map(t => t.ToTable("PaymentProducts"));
```

Doing so instructs Entity Framework to create the junction tables that allow a `Payment` to hold a collection of `Products`.

Comment: YES!!! Thank you! Removing the HasOptional with HasMany.WithMany and them mapping to a junction table did the trick! @nick_w thank you for solving it :)

Answer (score 0):

When creating your payment you should save it directly to the database. I don't think adding it to your account object would work because it's an entity that isn't being tracked by EF yet.

```
public ActionResult AddProduct(List<Product> products)
{
//var acc = Account.FetchAccountFromIdentity(User.Identity.GetUserName());
var username = User.Identity.GetUserName();
var acc = db.Accounts.First(u => u.EmailAddress == username);
var payment = new Payment();

foreach (var product in products)
{
    if (product.IsSelected)
    {
        var tempProduct = db.Products.Find(product.ProductID);
        payment.Products.Add(tempProduct);
        payment.PaymentStatus = enPaymentStatus.Pending;
        payment.Gross += tempProduct.Price;
        payment.Vat += tempProduct.Price * 0.2;
        payment.Net += payment.Gross - payment.Vat;
     }
}
payment.AccountID = acc.AccountID;
db.Payments.Add(payment);
db.SaveChanges();

return RedirectToAction("Pay", "Products", new {id = acc.AccountID} );
}
```

Comment: Whoever down-voted me could you please leave a comment and explain why?

Comment: Closest yet! @Shriike Your solution give the error: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[PPPv2.Models.Product]' to type 'PPPv2.Models.Product'. when we reach the line db.Payments.Add(payment)

Comment: The only place that I see a list of products is this line `payment.Products.Add(tempProduct);` could you try commenting that out and see if you still get the same error? Also it might be helpful adding the definition of Product to your message.

Comment: I've now added the Product model to the above. I would comment out payment.Products.Add(tempProduct), but I need it added to the payment before adding it to the account.

Comment: @Dezzamondo I know you need to save the product with the payments, but maybe for debugging purposes you could try taking out that line, using db.Payments.Create() instead of new Payment, taking out the new List in your Payment constructor, just to help narrow down the problem.